# Can't I edit JS from DevTools if it was written in an HTML file with a script tag? How to edit it?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-devtools

Suppose that I'm trying to change the "test" string that it doesn't appear on the console.

```html
<body>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () =>{
            console.log("test");
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

I was trying to edit the Javascript code from DevTools, but I can't edit this.  I googled why I couldn't edit it, and I found an answer that an HTML file can't be edit in the Sources panel.

[Can't edit HTML in Chrome dev tools Sources tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26473420/cant-edit-html-in-chrome-dev-tools-sources-tab)

So, I was trying to delete the line "console.log("test");" from the element tab. But, the "test" string was displayed on the console.

1. Can't I edit JS from DevTools if it was written in an HTML file with a script tag?
2. If question one is true, is there any other way to edit it?

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is no. The only way is to run the whole function in the console. But this is all temporarily. If you want to get rid of it you have to change the html. Why are you trying to change it in the DevTools? Do you have access to the files?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I can't access these files, because not local. These files get from a server.

Comment: That's why you need server access, otherwise anyone could edit all websites on the Internet :D

Comment: Indeed, no one can access the server and change it from a browser. However, I thought that the file once get from the server to the browser could be edited like a CSS file.

Comment: When the html is loaded then the function will be executed directly so it is impossible. But my question is why? What are you trying to do? Explain and maybe i can help because at the moment it makes no sense to me.

Comment: Thank you for your help. ok, I talk about it in more detail. Here is a function that uses the DOMContentload event. This code will be added to one of the pages in CMS (WordPress, Salesforce CMS, etc.). However, I can't add this code directly because I can't log in to the CMS service. I give the code to the person who adds it to the page. Therefore, I can confirm the code is working through a web browser only. Then, I checked the page added the code that used the DOMContentload event, but It is not working as expected. So, I want to debug this code through the web browser and hope I can do it.