# Chrome Dev Tools Elements Tab stopped working (can't right click any DOM Node and hover over Dom Node doesnt highlight anything)

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In the Elements Tab of Chrome Dev Tools I can't right click any DOM Node anymore. I'm talking about the following menu that right click usually opens:
[image]

Furtheremore usually if you hover over DOM Nodes in the Elements Tab, the actual element on the website will be highlighted. This also doesnt work anymore. I have to explicitly left click the DOM Node and only then the element on the website will be highlighted. Before that it would work even just on hover.

[image]

I tried restarting my Browser and resetting Preferences of Dev Tools to default. Nothing works.

Comment: Sounds like your keyboard modifier key like `Ctrl` is stuck. Try pressing and releasing all the modifiers on your keyboard.

Comment: @wOxxOm Sadly that didn't work. I don't think it's an issue with my keyboard. I tried googling all sorts of stuff but I just can't find a solution. Never heard of a broken chrome dev tool like that before. It's like I turned on some kind of weird Mode on but I don't know how or what.

Comment: Try making a new user profile and see if it works. If it does, try reinstalling Chrome.

Comment: @wOxxOm Okay so when I create a completely new user Profile the problem is gone. So the issue is somehow with my current user Profile. Thanks for figuring that out. I don't want to lose all my user settings though. Do you have any suggestions how to proceed? The only way I can think of is abandoning my user profile but that would suck so much.

Comment: By reinstalling Chrome I meant running its installer, which preserves the profile. Just in case, you can make a copy of your entire `user data` directory beforehand.

Comment: @wOxxOm Unfortunately reinstalling didn't work. I noticed that Chrome installed/updated earlier today though. So I assume that Chrome Auto Updated which resulted in my chrome dev tools breaking. I'm looking into reverting back latest Updates and if that doesnt work I guess I have to create a complete new user profile =(

Comment: Is the option "reveal on hover" enabled? https://puu.sh/IMWIi/daf52d4618.png

Comment: that option is checked for me

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Not sure if this will work for anyone else, but when I zoomed in on the Elements Tab (ctrl + mouse scroll wheel) right click began working again.

Comment: You can zoom back to normal once you've zoomed in a bunch, and it should still work. For those who don't know, this is a bug in Chrome itself, and reinstalling Chrome probably won't do anything.

Answer (score 11):

Yeah, it's the latest update.
I've found small solution. You need to click on 3 dots near the dom element https://prnt.sc/PwvcUE8OdSAf

Comment: Another option is to click the dom element and type $0 in console. I think Yours is an easier solution..

Answer (score 5):

Zoom in and zoom out with `ctrl + "-/+"` or `ctrl + scroll_wheel` till you cross the **100%** line, **make sure you zoom in and zoom out all the way**.

In this [Google support post](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/156373656/right-click-not-working-on-developers-tools-elements-tab?hl=en#:%7E:text=Try%20a%20quick%20browser%20reset,extension%20is%20causing%20the%20issue.&text=If%20that%20fixes%20the%20issue,know%20which%20extension%20caused%20it) suggest to reinstall Chrome.

You can also use the small three dots `...` at the left if this didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Zoomed-in on the Elements Tab (ctrl + mouse scroll wheel)or(ctrl+0) right click began working again.

Answer (score 1):

So I have identified that if the zoom percent is less that 100% and code in the Elements tab goes passed the end of the Elements display area and creates a scrollbar to scroll down the code (overflow), then right clicking code to display menu options becomes disabled (see screenshots). The only way to get the menu to appear is by clicking the three dots on the left of the element line item or zooming in to 100% or more.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5H29U.png

Answer (score 1):

Zoomed-in on the Elements Tab began working again.

ctrl+0 can zoomed-in to 100%

After confirmation, this function can only work if it is above 100%

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).